# Weird update behavior in portable MiKTeX version

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

Recently, I did a fresh installation of portable MiKTeX version "miktex-portable-2.9.6942.exe" on an USB stick; "miktex-portable-2.9.6942.exe" was downloaded from the MiKTeX website. After the first update on May 22nd I`v got 105 updated packages, both MiKTeX binary files as well as add-on packages coming along with the 2.9.6942 version. Now, with the update of today (May 28th) I get 84 packages to be updated. In MiKTeX console, I don't see anymore the source version of packages, but a flag in the right column of the console saying "to be repaired". This is somehow weired, because in the former version of MiKTeX I could compare  "Installed" and "Source" and see exactly what has changed. Along with this strange behavior related to the binary files other packages coming along with this version are not recognized as updatable (which is really, really bad, btw.). Can anyone confirm this observation? I have the feeling that the offered version "miktex-portable-2.9.6942.exe" (from January?) is so old, that it cannot be updated reasonably.
[image]

Comment: such questions should be better asked at the miktex github site: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: I did that already, but the respective task was more or less immediately closed as not applicable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be better an bug report to MiKTeX maintainer ...